# Using google maps api with javascript to render paint a world view with activity

Tags: javascript, google-maps

The main idea is that I would like to make a world map that shows activites as they progress on a timescale from a database. Would it be possible to do that with google maps in javascript? I found in the api you can render just about any polygon, but do you think there are some problems that will make it impossible to use as an efficient renderer for a large amount of markers or areas shifting in size? Any tips on how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can be done. CampaignMonitor.com does it with "World View" where you can watch your subscribers receive emails - it's pretty cool.